# Total angular momentum of a continuous body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, torque

I find the definition of *total angular momentum* $\mathbf{L}$ of a system of $n$ material points with respect to a given point $Q$ as the sum of the momenta $\ell_i=\mathbf{r}_i\times\mathbf{p}_i$ -where $\mathbf{r}_i$ is the position of point $i$ with respect to $Q$ and $\mathbf{p}_i$ its momentum- of the $n$ points:$$\mathbf{L}:=\sum_{i=1}^n\ell_i$$whose derivative is $$\frac{d\mathbf{L}}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i=1}^n \ell_i=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d \ell_i}{dt}$$where it is easily proved that $\frac{d \ell_i}{dt}=\mathbf{r}_i\times\mathbf{F}_i=\boldsymbol{\tau}_i$, where $\mathbf{F}_i$ is the resulting force acting on point $i$. Since the torques of the forces exerced by the $n$ points on each other nullify each other, we can write $$\frac{d\mathbf{L}}{dt}=\sum\boldsymbol{\tau}_{\text{ext}}$$where only the torques due to external forces appear in the sum.

I wonder, but I find no resource about the issue, whether such formula is also valid for continuous bodies. If it is, how do we define $\mathbf{L}$?

Is the total angular momentum $\mathbf{L}=\int_V \rho(\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{q})\times\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x})dxdydz$ for a body extended on the domain $V\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, with density $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ and velocity $\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x})$ at point $\mathbf{x}$, with respect to a point having coordinates $\mathbf{q}$? If $\mathbf{L}$ is equal to such an integral, does the equality $\frac{d\mathbf{L}}{dt}= \int_V \frac{d(\rho\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{v} )}{dt} dV$ holds, and, if it does, how can the validity of the derivation under the integral sign be proved?

$\infty$ thanks for any answer!

Comment: For the differentiation under the integral sign, see the [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Very interesting: thank you!!! The problem is that I cannot express the dependencies of the function $\rho(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{q})\times\mathbf{v}$ from $\mathbf{x}$ and $t$...